# WPF Extended Toolkit Control in Custom Control not pulling through to form?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, xceed

I am using the Xceed Extended WPF Toolkit for the Integer Up Down Control. I have installed this via Nuget.

I have the integrated into a custom control which contains other normal textboxes and button etc.

This custom control I then put in a tab control on a Window. Everything shows correctly apart from this IntegerUpDown which shows as an empty box. (It is fine when looking at the custom control in design)

I have added the namespace to both the control and window so am not sure what the problem is. Everything is inside one project so I don't think references are a problem.

Any ideas of what I could be missing?

Control XAML:

```
<Label Grid.Row="3" Content="Quantity of Tickets:" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Label>
<xctk:IntegerUpDown Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Name="numTickets"></xctk:IntegerUpDown>
```

Form XAML:

```
<TabItem Header="New Booking">
      <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
           <btc:NewBooking></btc:NewBooking>
      </Grid>
 </TabItem>
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Please post your XAML.

Comment: Hi. apologies have added control and form XAML for relevant bits

Comment: You should include full XAML for `<btc:NewBooking>` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to do that :( the <btc:NewBooking> is just the control in the Control XAML what bit are you interested in?

Comment: When i use my "equivalent", `<local:UserControl1>` it works with no problem. So, I'm wondering what exactly you did there.

Comment: I have added the namespace xmlns:btc="clr-namespace:MyProject.Controls" it appears in the designer correctly just not when debugging :(

Comment: The problem is not in your XAML itself then, but how you project is organized.

Comment: What do I need to re-organize? I've just tried with another similar Nuget Control and it's worked as expected?

Comment: I have a single project... with a folder called Controls and another called Forms which is where the control and form/window are

Comment: Even when moving it into the root it does not work when accessed as <local:UserControl> would you be able to provide me with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

**MainWindow:**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
    x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Margin="0">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem 1">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem 2">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

**UserControl:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication8.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Content="Quantity of Tickets:" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Label>
        <xctk:IntegerUpDown Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Name="numTickets"></xctk:IntegerUpDown>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Both `MainWindow` and `UserControl` are at the same level in the project structure:

[image]

---

**EDIT:** One more thing, make sure your `UserControl` is fully contained by the `MainWindow` and you do NOT have something like this:

[image]

That would cause the `IntegerUpDown` look like an empty box, like you described.

Comment: I've copied my user control to a new project and it works so I have absolutely no idea what's going on haha! Thanks for your time, effort and help :)

Comment: I FOUND THE CULPRIT!! I had an setter in the app.xaml to put a margin of 5,5,5,5 around every Grid. Which was obviously interfering with this control as well as many others as I found later.

Comment: I'm glad you did it, congrats !